# What does "good job" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms, colloquialisms

What is the meaning of "good job" in English? I have heard some people use that instead of "do not be tired".

Comment: Other than its occasional use as sarcasm, it means exactly the literal meaning of the words: "Congratulations on performing the job well."

Comment: You might consider asking questions like this one at the site for [ell.SE].

Comment: “Do not be tired” is not an idiom in English. It is also not something anyone would be likely to say in any normal situation. If someone is tired, they are tired. Ordering them not to be will not change that. It's like saying, “Don't be thirsty”—pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase is commonly spoken to one who has done something worthy of praise. For example, if a sales representative brings in $10 million on a deal, his boss may tell him that he did a "good job." In this sense, the definition is quite literal.

However, "good job" can also be used in a sarcastic tone. In this case, the recipient is being mocked for something he has done poorly.

Comment: Phrases cannot be given to someone.